# Open stack Octavia quota exceeded for resources and failed

Tags: networking, load-balancing, openstack, openstack-neutron

I using open stack Victoria on Ubuntu and i want to use from Octavia.
but when i create a load balancer, it failed and in Octavia worker logs show this:
`ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server neutronclient.common.exceptions.OverQuotaClient: Quota exceeded for resources: ['security_group'].`
what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in plain text meaning by `'Quota exceeded for resources: ['security_group']` tips, the number of your **security groups** equal or bigger than the value of `openstack quota show -c secgroups -f value your_project_name`.

Maybe the main point is `create a load balancer`, and spend the resource, check from this: "[The global amount of Octavia loadbalancers is constrained by the service project quotas](https://bugs.launchpad.net/tripleo/+bug/1769896)".

Quote the problem and resolve:

```
Description of problem:
LB creation creates neutron ports, security groups and instances(cores, RAM, keypairs, etc). 

Those objects, when created with LB create command execution are needed not to be omitted while planning the cloud with Octavia.  

Possible solutions 1 of 3 : 
a- Agreed quota numbers
b- Unlimited quota numbers
c- Documentation of the effect of LB creation on the resources in neutron and nova so the operator could include that in the cloud planning and services quotas configuration.
```

Comment: thnx... i deleted some secgroups that not used and it worked.